# How to terminate app in Android Studio-- app running on separate device

Tags: android

The app runs great, but there doesn't seem to be a way to terminate it. There is a "Terminate Application" button, but it's greyed out, as seen here:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wIuGhd9.png]

I've tried pressing the Home and the Back buttons on the device many times, to no effect.

The app is from the second lesson in the Android Studio tutorials, so it's the bare minimum amount of code (it's one lesson after Hello World). Is the problem that there's no onClose() event, so it just keeps running?

Edit: I should add that I think it's still running because messages are still coming through the debugger. Although, it's just occurred to me-- is the debugger simply listening to the device, and those messages aren't coming from my program, but are just background messages from the device?

Edit2: **Solved** thanks to dexter. You need to select the process name (com.mycompany.myfirstapp) before the terminate button will become active.

Comment: You need to select the process `com.mycompany.myfirstapp` and then press the `Terminate Application` button.

Comment: I am a newb and can't find the DDMS perspective. Can somebody help?

Comment: Please note that the "Terminate Application" button will move from logcat to the new device monitor soon, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246928842

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to select the process `com.mycompany.myfirstapp` and then press the **Terminate Application** button.

Comment: I can't see the list of processes. The logcat prints infinitely and no app is shown on my phone (ADB). What do I miss here?

Answer (score 11):

As above mentioned,we can terminates the apps which are running in an emulator or real device using Android Device Monitor.These are the steps to follow.

01)

[image: 1st Step]

To open the Android Device Monitor,click the android logo(24th icon from left).when you take the cursor on the icon it will display as "Android Device Monitor".

02)

[image: 2nd Step]
You will get a screen like this.In here in device part it shows the emulators or connected android device to the computer.

03)

[image: 3rd Step]

Select the device.Then it will shows the current apps running in the device.

04)

[image: 4th Step]

Select the app which you want to terminate and click the stop icon above.This will terminates your app.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the process list and terminate your running app by opening the Android Device Monitor, located here:

[image]

Comment: So where is the stop button? Even the program can not be closed X

Answer (score 1):

That just happened to me.
The solution is to press on the "Debug app" button ( the bug next to the green triangle). A window will pop up that says that it will stop the Emulator. It wont, but Now you will be able to press terminate button.
Noam.

Comment: How can a 'big' program doesn't have a stop button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and simply terminate your app to simulate process death.
Note: Open your app by physical device or emulator, send it to the background by press the "HOME" button, then do the steps and bring it to the foreground by launcher.
if run your app directly by android studio, after termination, it restarts from begin.

[image: Step1]
[image: Step2]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to simulate an Android app kill from the Android system while the app is in background is:

1. Run the app on your device or emulator
2. Open any screen of your app, usually the screen you would like to test against restoring it's state
3. Put the app in background (use the device Home button or Recent apps button)
4. Once your app is in background, use your terminal (could be Android Studio's terminal, or your computer's terminal, or anything which is a shell with ADB command available) and run the following command there:

```
adb shell am kill {your app package name}
```

Example for app with package name **xx.yy.zz** would be:

```
adb shell am kill xx.yy.zz
```

5. Once the adb command is finished, try to restore your app from the background by using your device Recent apps (the square) button

That's the pattern to follow in any IDE, in any version of Android studio etc. and it should aways work.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Select the process which you want to terminate, and click on Terminate Application.

Comment: does not add any value to the question. Which selection , which terminate option. Please consider adding details.