# Why won't emulator window close in Android Studio 1.1.0 when I select Stop from Run menu?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Not only won't AS close the emulator window, there's no way to click something in the emulator window to close it myself. (The Windows title bar is off screen and I can't drag window.)

So I have to use Windows 7 Task Manager, upon which I usually get a Windows message saying "emulator has stopped working... looking for solution" and no solution is ever found.

I used Android Device Manager to change startup size option to different from auto setting, finally trying `10dp on device = 1 px on sctreen` and the emulator size is still same--window title bar is off screen.

Is this just how it is?

EDIT--

Whenever ANY emulator is running, AS 1.1.0 and the emulator and Java take OVER 3 GIGAbytes of physical memory (emulator itself almost 2GB), leaving ZERO MB free. (I have 8 GB RAM.)

Is this part of the problem?

EDIT #2--

Here's the poop for Nexus One

```
Name: Nexus_One_Edited_1_API_21

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\Dov\.android\avd\Nexus_One_Edited_1_API_21.avd

Target: Google APIs (API level 21)

Skin: nexus_one

SD Card: 100M

Snapshot: no

hw.lcd.density: 240

hw.dPad: no

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.camera.back: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 200M

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

runtime.network.latency: none

skin.dynamic: no

hw.keyboard: yes

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.device.hash2: MD5:7c7cc73cfc403e08db67d4e460077256

hw.ramSize: 512

tag.id: google_apis

tag.display: Google APIs

hw.sdCard: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: User

hw.mainKeys: yes

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.trackBall: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus One (Edited) 1

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.battery: yes

AvdId: Nexus_One_Edited_1_API_21

hw.sensors.orientation: no

hw.audioInput: yes

hw.camera.front: none

hw.gps: yes

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus One (Edited) 1 API 21

snapshot.present: no

vm.heapSize: 32

runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

Here's what I see as soon as I change the resolution. Note that the "X" box to close the window is shown BUT the error prohibits clicking it. I accepted the Debug option, so the C++ debugger opened, but clicking the "X" to close emulator window was ignored. After closing the C++ debugger, the emulator window was still showing but clicking the "X" was ignored.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the emulator in the task bar and click close. It still gives you the error, but it is easier than task manager or window resolution.

If it makes you feel any better, I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369574/how-to-terminate-app-in-android-studio-app-running-on-separate-device.)

The option I used is to go to "Tools -> Android -> SDK manager -> Stop".
No need to change screen resolution for this.