# How to stop android studio from running

Tags: android, android-studio

How to I stop my code from running in Android Studio? I have tried selecting the program under the Java folder, but the "Terminate Application" button is grayed out. It's really annoying how the long is going crazy even though I have ended the app on my phone...

Here is a screenshot of my screen if it helps:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369574/how-to-terminate-app-in-android-studio-app-running-on-separate-device

Comment: I think your app has already stopped. Shown there are just system event logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the lines in the logcat that keep appearing even when you app is stopped, this is normal, your phone keeps running other apps and logging status messages.

To suppress this output try selecting you application in the drop down menu on the right to show only your app's output

Comment: Or disconnect your device, or click anywhere in the logcat window to stop the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

[From this answer:](http://You%20need%20to%20select%20the%20process%20com.mycompany.myfirstapp%20and%20then%20press%20the%20Terminate%20Application%20button.)

You need to select the **process** com.mycompany.myfirstapp and then press the Terminate Application button.